# Buttons, scroll bars and icons are small and blurry in win7

Tags: windows-7, gui

After I created a new user on my computer, my normal user has strange gui errors. I tried a lot with changing DPI settings and so on, but nothing helped, my buttons, scrollbars and icons are somehow too small. The picture is made with 100% setting for the DPI. I searched all the web but only found beginner tutorials so far... So any idea how i could reset this?

[image: win7 gui error]

Comment: Did you try changing font sizing in the Display options? Control Panel-->Display-->Appearance, and select the Font Size drop-down. I'm not at my Windows 7 machine right now, but in XP this certainly solves the issues with scrollbars and window buttons.

Comment: Try to re-apply Windows Classic theme from Personalization settings. The sizes of icons and scroll bars can be modified (by applications), re-applying the theme should reset those settings to the default values stored in the theme file. Also try to select another theme, Aero or Basic, and then return to Classic.

Comment: thanks ALEXEY that was the solution... switching to a completely different theme and then customizing that again to me needs. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution was (Alexey Ivanov):

"Re-apply Windows Classic theme from Personalization settings. The sizes of icons and scroll bars can be modified (by applications), re-applying the theme should reset those settings to the default values stored in the theme file."

this worked! switching to a completely different theme and then customizing that again to my needs.